# Laptop screen powering off - heat issue?

Tags: laptop, display, gpu, cooling, overheating

I have an old 2008 Dell Vostro 1500 with Intel gl960/gm965 chipset with Nvidia 8400M-GS graphics card, and Windows 10 x86 freshly installed.

The issue: after 4 or 5 minutes browsing, the screen goes off. I can hear the laptop is powered on, the hard-drive is working, even the lights are on. Just screen is off. And stay this way until I restart.

The same behaviour doesn't occur if I'm in bios panel changing settings, or if I left the Windows logged on without doing nothing.
If I just let it powered on, the screen keeps displaying, after 30 minutes and on (maximum test I did).

This is an empty windows installation, and was occurring with an old version too. I've already changed hard disk (with a Ps4 one), did memtest and replaced thermal paste on cpu and gpu.

Kept windows 10 x86 default nvidia graphic driver, and then updated with latest one, nothing solved.

Is it a hardware issue, or is it possible that just "dried thermal pads" under gpu heatsink could be causing this issue?

I don't have enough time to open Aida64 and do a stress test to discover, or even read gpu temperature sensors. Is there any command I can quickly type to check?

Thank you all for any comment.

Ps: I don't have an option to disable gpu, as this laptop doesn't have an integrated graphic card on cpu.

Comment: Could also be a marginal connection of the ribbon cable from motherboard to screen, or a cold solder joint on the motherboard ribbon connector. Can you perform minor surgery on the laptop to get at that cable, disconnect/reconnect it, and power up with it still exposed? If it fails after a few minutes, hit the connection with compressed gas to cool it off (Boyle's Law) and see if it works again, albeit briefly. That would be easier than removing the GPU heatsink assembly to clean and reapply the thermal compound. Could also remove Windows completely from the equation with a Linux LiveUSB.

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY. I'm looking for cold solder joints on internet. I've already opened the laptop to change thermal paste both on cpu and gpu, but didn't looked for this. I'm not much into hardware fix. I'll try to open it again and look for the ribbon cable (didn't see it at first) and look for cold solder joints. There's a chance there may not be any ribbon cable, maybe soldered directly through PCB? I'll try to check the place on PCB where the screen cable connects to.

Comment: @K7AAY, didn't opened it again yet, but did some tests booting from Linux pendrive and worked successfully. Than, tried uninstalling Nvidia driver and it is working (although not with the best resolution). The problem occurred both with the windows update Nvidia driver and with the one I downloaded directly from Nvidia web page. Now, after removing the driver, the "device manager" shows a generic pnp monitor being used as driver. It's working. Don't know where to go next. Maybe with Nvidia driver the computer tries to use some hardware part that is damaged. Could it be?

Comment: Tested with OEM Dell driver from 2008 and still same issue. I'm having to keep the Nvidia device disabled (using "generic Microsoft pnp monitor" as the device). The main catch on this workaround is that simple things like moving a window around cause a big spike on cpu usage. Starting windows menu also do that, cause everything is being rendered by cpu.

Comment: I'll disassemble and look for cold solder joint on gpu, cause if it was a ribbon cable issue, it would occur with any operational system/driver , right? And my problem is occurring only if gpu is enabled (i.e., driver installed and device enabled).

Comment: If a ribbon cable issue, it would manifest with any OS. However, it may only appear when a particular graphics mode is used.

Comment: Indeed. Tested again and only when opengl is required is that the screen goes off. Tried with different driver versions, using DDU (driver Uninstaller) between those tries, all failing because of opengl.

Comment: And, if you boot from a Linux LiveUSB,, and invoke OpenGL within Linux, does it fail? Download Lubuntu 19.10 @ ubuntu.com/download/flavours Check for download errors by  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a Linux LiveUSB on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows w/ the Rufus Windows open source app.

Comment: I'll give it a try. My only issue is enabling Nvidia driver without rebooting the system (which would empty all settings done at the live USB). But I'll search on internet how to restart video without rebooting.

Comment: Hi there. I couldn't make it to find cold solder joints at plain eye. Had to leave windows using "Default Generic Monitor PNP" monitor drive, disabling GPU device. Thank you for all the help, indeed was very informative.